# React dev tools in CEF?

Tags: reactjs, chromium-embedded

I'm building a react app to run in a CEF frame.

Is there any way to use react dev tools with CEF? I don't need to ship the tools with the app, purely for my own dev usage.

Comment: CEF does not yet support extensions so unlikely. You might be able to use remote debugging.

Comment: See also CEF forum: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16649&p=41339

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative (and in my opinion the best approach), develop your React app separately from the .Net/CEF app, then debug from the Chrome browser installed in your machine (from which you can install the React dev tools, if you haven't).

If you're self hosting your web api from the CEF app, it can become finicky sometimes (CORS, etc.), but should be pretty easy to get around with.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing, but it would be nice to debug it in the real environment being seeded from real data. I suppose I can build a data bridge, but it's still wouldn't be the raw env. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: As a follow up to this, I ended up building a faux-data wrapper in debug mode to run in a normal Chrome browser. It works sufficiently, but I still would love to debug in CEF proper. If anyone finds a solution, let me know!